# Fscanf that reads only a last word from a file

Tags: c, file, scanf

I'm trying to insert words from a file into a binary tree.The insert function works when not reading from a file also when I tried to print every read string after fscanf it it also works,but when I try to insert it into a tree only the last string from a file is read.Why does this happen?

```
    while(1){

    if(fscanf(f,"%s %d",string,&x)==EOF)
          break;

      tree=insert(tree,string,x);
    }
```

Comment: You're not making a copy of `string` before you insert it. The `insert` function is just saving a pointer, and all the tree entries point to the same string.

Comment: Please provide a complete example program showing the bug, to save us from guessing what the rest of your code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert()` doesn't make a copy of the string, it just stores the pointer you give it in the tree. So all the tree entries contain a pointer to the same string, which you're overwriting each time you call `fscanf`.

The same problem happens with the `x` argument, you're passing the same pointer each time. You need to allocate a new `int` for each of the values as well.

```
while (1) {
    if (fscanf(f, "%s %d", string, x) == EOF) {
        break;
    }
    char *new_str = malloc(strlen(string)+1);
    strcpy(new_str, string);
    int *new_int = malloc(sizeof(*x));
    *new_int = *x;
    tree = insert(tree, new_str, new_int);
}
```

Comment: This will always insert the same `int *`.

Comment: @RolandIllig No it won't. Integers are passed by value to functions.

Comment: But `x` is not an `int`, it is an `int *`. Otherwise the call to `fscanf` would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Oops, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
while (fscanf(f, "%s %d", string, &val) == 2) {
    char *copy = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
    if (copy == NULL)
        break;
    strcpy(copy, string);
    insert(copy, val);
}
```

Note the error handling for `fscanf`, which checks if both fields could be read. Also note the `&` in front of `val`, which probably prevents a compiler warning. By the way, you should enable all available compiler warnings, so you don't have to search for the bugs yourself.

Comment: The second argument to `insert()` should be `int *`, you're passing `int`.

Comment: I think inserting the `int` is more sensible in this case, though this is not clear from the question.

Comment: The tree might be designed to allow any type of data to be stored, so the value would be `void*`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but is it safe using strdup since it's not part of standard c library?my actual code did have '&' just forgot it while typing it in here

Comment: Next time, prefer copy & paste over typing it. :)

Comment: Regarding `strdup`, it depends on the platform you are developing for.